# Test automation -Problem with choosing the item from dropdown

Tags: typescript, automation, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests

I want to choose item from dropdown on a modal window.
The function is

```
setItemFromDropDownList(urlElement: ElementFinder, n: number) {

        this.clickElement(urlElement);
        urlElement.all(by.tagName('li')).get(n - 1).click();
    }
```

But this gave me an error Message:
  Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 1, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, li)

Element is mapped by id

```
serviceDropdown: ElementFinder=element(by.id('servicePhase'));
```

One of items in html

```
<p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c8-390 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" class="ui-dropdown-item ui-corner-all" aria-label="Paczka pocztowa zagraniczna"><!----><span class="ng-star-inserted">Paczka pocztowa zagraniczna</span><!----></li></p-dropdownitem>
```

I think its cosed becouse the dropdown is on the modal window, so what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to track when the test fails, maybe it fails because the drop down list value is not displayed on page, you need to wait first to be visible before selecting it:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
setItemFromDropDownList(urlElement: ElementFinder, n: number) {    
    this.clickElement(urlElement);     
    browser.driver.wait(function () {
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(urlElement.all(by.tagName('li')).get(n - 1)), 10000);
    urlElement.all(by.tagName('li')).get(n - 1).click();
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your solution, but i'm also find such a way:
mainLib.clickElement(dropdownName);
dropdownName.all(by.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/p-dropdownitem[1]/li')).click();
and it works.